# PHP support for Google App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Does anyone have any idea as to when the [Google App](http://code.google.com/appengine/) engine will support PHP?

Comment: I'm going to go with sometime.

Comment: @Paolo : Thought I'd go ahead and get all of the poll answers out of the way.  Nevermind that polls don't belong on SO.

Comment: @alf: I doubt you'll get any (helpful) answers here that you wouldn't get by asking on the GAE newsgroup.

Comment: Sounded like a simple question ... not necessarily a poll.

Comment: Google just announced PHP support on https://developers.google.com/events/io/

Comment: Why is this closed ? Morons! Very good question. Google just introducted PHP support for App Engine today, check the official presentation: https://gaeforphp.appspot.com/

Answer (score 2):

When hell freezes? =) Nah. But I think only Google knows what's next on Google App Engine. Google and maybe a select few key developers around the projects that are candidates.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that's slated for after Google AeroPork launches.

Comment: You should see what they did to my answer(s).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Google knows.

This question should be posed to the project's [discussion group(s)](http://code.google.com/appengine/groups.html).

Comment: Because it's common sense. If anyone has "any idea as to when the Google App engine will support PHP", then its developers most certainly do. I then gave Alf a pointer into investigating further into a source of more focused expertise on the subject. Critical much? :)

Comment: My mistake. I thought you were implying that Google does currently support PHP.

Comment: Oh, I understand the confusion. Sorry for that ambiguity there.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the latest [roadmap](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html) you will see that they are indeed working on a new language runtime. However, I very much doubt it will be PHP. It seems people on the Net [expect it to be Java](http://www.controlenter.in/2008/10/java-support-to-appengine-to-counter-microsofts-cloud-initiatives-microsoft-strata/), but until June 2009 (if all goes well) we'll just have to speculate.