# Why "not" Google App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, hosting

I've heard of GAE and even though it doesn't support PHP, people have gotten around this limitation by using Quercus I think (I haven't tried it, but supposedly it works). But what factors should I consider when evaluating whether it's a match for me? For example, what made you **not** go with GAE? Or if you went with it, what are you not happy about?

thanks

**Edit:**

Thanks to those who saw value in the question and defended it. I've seen questions here that were much less programming-related than mine and which were left open. In terms of it being a dupe, it isn't in anyway. That other question was specifically about PHP support; mine is about why not GAE in general (the php was a sidenote). I doubt the guy that yelled "dupe" even read both questions to see how mine is obviously so much different. You can vote it reopened if you still see value in it. **Some good answers were already coming in, too bad the 5 of you killed a Perfectly Good Thing.** I voted for a reopen, 4 more people could hop on if interested.

Comment: Not programming related and duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538524/php-support-for-google-app-engine-closed

Comment: OK, I get how this can be a duplicate (kind of). But how is this "not programming related"?

Comment: FWIW, i voted to close because you're asking for individual experiences - that's a topic better suited to a discussion board, which SO is **not** (see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/where-can-i-find-interesting-programming-discussions). No idea why others voted for NPR.

Comment: this is why I wish microsoft would've grew a pair and offered a small amount of resources for free to compete with google, since they have a wide variety of language support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because GAE is less flexible and tightly coupled to Google's framework.

Comment: Less flexible than what?

Comment: Less flexible than deploying it to a VPS.