# PHP on the Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

How can i run a PHP script on the Google App Engine?

I know that Java and Python are supported. Is PHP possible?

Comment: See [PHP support for Google App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538524/php-support-for-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* just about using [Quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/) but it's not a full implementation last time I checked. It basically compiles your PHP down to Java and runs that through the Java Runtime.

My opinion: it's a hack. You'll probably find thing breaking and you'll probably have a really lousy experience with it.

But it might work for you so feel free to try it out.

Answer (score 3):

The Google App Engine does not support php natively, even though [it](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary%20Log%20Component) remains at the [top of the wish list on the GAE issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).

However, you should be able to run php scripts using a Java implementation of PHP, such as [Quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/). You may want to check out the following article for further reading on the topic:

- [Quercus on the Google App Engine](http://blog.caucho.com/?p=187)

Answer (score 2):

PHP for App Engine is now in Limited Preview:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/